# java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is denied) error while capturing screenshot in selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, takesscreenshot

Below is the error that am getting while running the script to capture screenshot in selenium webdriver using Java.

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
>   Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4c9d18015e755cee48f953ddc3f2f-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#1024}) on port 16655
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
>   [1570714638.101][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 77.
>   [1570714640.126][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
>   Oct 10, 2019 7:07:22 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
>   [1570714645.280][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
>   FAILED: takeScreenshot
>   **java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\share\OneDrive\Desktop\Screenshots (Access is denied)**
>
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler.copyFile(FileHandler.java:138)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler.copy(FileHandler.java:117)
>       at tests.ScreenshotTest.takeScreenshot(ScreenshotTest.java:29)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

===============================================
    Default test

## Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

===============================================
Default suite

## Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Comment: Check that your user has the privilege to read/write C:\Users\share\OneDrive\Desktop\Screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Add This to your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And then request premissions in the app like something like this

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA){
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                try {
                   getImageFromCamera();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Needed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
              getImageFromGallery();
            }
            else{
                Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Needed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```